# How would life work if Humanoids had fox paws instead of feet?

Tags: creature-design, humanoid

Hiya I'm writing a fantasy story that features Kitsunes. Now my Kitsunes resemble the Classic Kitsunes of myth (humanoid with fox tails and ears) but mine have the added addition of fox paws instead of human feet. Now I'm curious how would life differ if humans had paws instead of feet? I would imagine our paw pads would allow us to walk on rocks and other debris without injury and maybe they would be able to run faster as there claws would allow traction. But what else? Wouldn't there paws stink more?

Comment: Humans can walk on rough ground, it just takes practice and building-up the skin of the feet. Do you mean the walk on the balls of their feet ie. no heels? You want to know if they'd smell? Can you pare it down to a single question please. One question per thread is the rule, making multiple questions in their own threads and linking them is fine though. As before, take our [tour] and browse the [help] for guidance to our ways.

Comment: "_How would everything be different_" is an invitation to a discussion, or to write a book. This sort of request is a poor fit for a Q&A site. You should focus down a bit, concentrate on the specifics. Ask things that can be answered without thousands of lines of text.

Comment: Are these paws on both feet and hands ?

Answer (score 3):

I'll start now by saying that apart from you wanting them to walk around barefoot, there's little stopping them from making [digitigrade-style shoes](https://www.deviantart.com/remarin/art/Shoes-for-people-on-the-digitigrade-spectrum-752383432).

As for the differences in digitigrade canid legs, assuming they do indeed have no shoes, your kitsunes will have some substantial differences:

- Compared to an equally barefoot human, they'd probably be better at climbing since they have both ape hands and cat claws on their feet (assuming their upper limbs have normal human nails), meaning they will be able to get more traction for climbing (this will also vary depending on what type of fox legs their legs resemble most, with species like gray foxes being great climbers with retractable claws). The fox leg structure can also be flexible enough to allow for decent climbing ability, again depending on what kind of fox it's modeled after.
- They have the potential to be better sprinters. Sure their claws could give them more traction than your average human sole, but that'd mean they'd only be as fast as someone with equal physique and good running shoes. The thing giving them the extra potential is their digitigrade leg structure (you said fox paws so in assuming their legs also follows the fox's digitigrade structure), which is naturally more adapted for better sprinting ability. This will however come, most likely, at the cost of being worse overall at keeping their balance. I'd say their ability to run for long periods won't be overly affected, since they are still capable of sweating. Essentially, they'll probably be able to outsprint a normal person, but will also be more likely to fall in they trip.
- as for bodily smell, it depends. If the region has fur, it'll probably be more prone to being smelly. If they also have scent glans on their paws like in red foxes, then it'll definitely have a strong smell, because they're meant to be that way. However, an important factor will also be whether they wear shoes and wash their paws regularly (as well as other measures humans take to make sure our own hairy region do not keep unwanted strong scents). Paws with scent glands will naturally be prone to have a stronger smell than those without them however.

Those are the main changes I see. Other things such as how bad they are at sitting down (see ostriches and other ratites), how flexible their legs are when compared to a normal human's, etc will depend on how exactly these are structures and would require a more in-depth anatomical analysis I can't give, because my attempts to find any form of musculature study on a hypothetical bipedal feline were not successful nor happy.

*However*, if by paws you just meant regular human feet with paw pads, claws and minimal modifications to the average human structure, the noticeable changes will be only be on things like basic maintenance and maybe a better climbing ability, but that's about it, because at this point your kitsunes are only slightly different from a guy who refused to wear shoes throughout most of his life in terms of protection from debris and rocks.

Comment: Ahem: We [*already make* dog shoes](https://www.amazon.com/dog-shoes/s?k=dog+shoes). Most would be too small for digitigrade humanoids, but that's just due to the market; most domestic dogs have smaller paws. Note that, while some of these are just glorified socks, others have all the features you'd expect out of modern human shoes.

Answer (score 2):

**Not handy for walking stairs or ladders**

Walking stairs requires bending over forward a little bit.. and straight forward walk up. I wonder if these fox paws on bipedals would be too much on the side, for walking stairs. Of course you could go quadrupedal (use your hands) to get up the stairs.. but upright ? would that work ?

For ladders, quadrupedal action is needed, but I wonder if a fox legs could handle the balance needed. CG (center of gravity) will be lowered.

**Not handy for swimming**

Long, straight legs allow a variety of swimming techniques. Humans will "outswim* these creatures.

**Very good at volleyball**

Jumping legs and free forelimbs. Great for volleyball.

[image]

**Not good at soccer**

A bipedal human-size fox could probably outrun Messi, but it will need  kangaroo-style jumps. In soccer, it is illegal to keep the ball with you, so for each jump, an accurate kick is needed. I wonder if that can be done with a normal soccer ball.

**Handy to have predator speed and use less energy for moving around**

You'd get around faster, for short distances you really don't need a bicycle or car, your energy use for walking prevents you from walking longer distances now.

Despite being bipedal and not quadrupedal, I'd like to have feet like these..

[image]

Guess I could *learn* handling these limbs to walk straight and upright.. *and* you can jump (like kangaroos) *and* run fast. Many advantages.

Ape feet  like ours were built to grab tree branches, rather than living on a surface. Australopitecus and Erectus adapted their feet a bit, to bipedalism on the ground, but the basic building plan of running predators is something we "humans" can be jealous for. Made for speed and energy effectiveness..

https://www.google.com/search?q=fox+paws&tbm=isch&source=iu

**In case of forelimbs too: Not handy for writing and fine work !**

I've put that in a comment question, the title only talks about "feet". On big advantage apes have: fingers.  Not having fingers would mean a huge difference in many aspects of life. Not having toes would make less difference.  Flexible, long fingers are needed to e.g. climb a ladder.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on the paws**

First off, a right up standing human needs to have some surface to stand on. If the paws size is increased relatively to the legs, we can see the paws have less surface. They are smaller as the fixes are made to be quadrupleds. They walk on all fours, giving them more contact points for balance and traction. Their physique is also low to the ground, giving them another balance advantage. Humans don't have such advantages, so they need both bigger feet and musculature that allows for balance. Just imagine yourself leaning with your legs several directions and pay attention to all that happens. Now imagine the small fox paws. It just isn't good. So first off, we need relatively giant fox paws.

Traction is about equal if paws are made to be giant. Otherwise they are very slippery thanks to little surface area.

A side note. Claws aren't primarily for purchase. They *can* offer help, but this is generally better done with other things. Like a foot that can wrap around things for more contact area. In addition, feet also wrinkle when wet. This gives more purchase when in a wet environment. Paws are again smaller and less advanced in this, as the fox doesn't require as much thanks to his build and quadrupled movement.

Paws do have little cushions, but feet are originally also good in many environments. In some areas of the world this is still the main method. Interestingly there is no verdict yet whether bare feet of shoes is better and modern science is trying to figure that out. The act of putting on shoes does make the feet protect itself less with (dead) skin layers and be in general more sensitive. These layers act suspiciously like the peds on paws. Paws to barefoot comparison of injury and pain is difficult, but I would say there no advantage for either. Paws have an advantage when they are on a quadrupled, but if on a human and made giant, they have the same amount of pressure on each compared to feet.

If the paws have fur, they are able to stay in cold environments. Yet when exerting themselves they contribute a bit to overheating, as they can't lose heat as easily thanks to the fur.